# Naming a Index using cypher for neo4j 2.0

Tags: indexing, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

Suppose i have graph where each user has label 'user' and property 'name' 
According to Neo4j 2.0 documentation we can create index using following cypher command

```
CREATE INDEX ON :user(name);
```

However if write a Cypher query using START clause like:

```
start n=node:user(name='john') return n
```

Then i am getting the following error

```
MissingIndexException: Index `user` does not exist
```

My question is how can i define the name of index in first place. I know that in Neo4j 2.0 using start clause is optional. However if i need to use them what is the best way to proceed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing the concepts of legacy indexes and the new 2.0 label-based indexes. Instead of using the `START` clause, use the `MATCH` clause, like so:

```
MATCH (n:user)
WHERE n.name='john' // this causes an index lookup
RETURN n
```

Also note that Cypher style usually uses initial case names for labels, like `:User`. Labels are case-sensitive.

Comment: Wouldn't `MATCH (n:user {name: 'john'}) RETURN n` trigger an index lookup as well?

Comment: Yep. I didn't want to give both to limit confusion, but yes it does. I prefer the WHERE syntax for most things, personally.